# Is it possible to construct a Tree data model using Java 8 Streams

Tags: tree, java-8, java-stream

I am investigating Java 8 streams.

I am currently stuck attempting to construct a classic tree structure by streaming a file where each record describes a Parent Child relationship.

I would like my solution to be able to construct a Tree from input data records that resemble the following examples:-

```
Parent A - Child B
Parent A - Child C
Parent A - Child D
Parent A - Child E
Parent B - Child F
Parent B - Child G
Parent C - Child H
Parent D - Child I
Parent G - Child J
```

I would like to either construct a `LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>`

e.g. end up with

```
A - B, C, D, E
B - F, G
C - H
D - I
G - J
```

The closest I get fails with duplicate key

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = stream.sorted().map(line -> line.split("-")).flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line)).collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), Arrays::asList));
```

Or using the following `Node` value object

```
public class Node {

    private final String name;
    private Node parent;
    private List<Node> children = new LinkedList<>();

}
```

Construct all tree nodes and with fully populated children node Lists direct from stream my input file.

Comment: Your first example is more like a multi-valued map than a tree. What do you aim for? A multimap or a tree structure similar to your second example? If you aim for a tree structure, does your input data actually guarantee a tree-like structure (e.g. single root node, connected, acyclic)?

Comment: @NándorElődFekete either a Multi-valued map or a tree will satisfy my requirements. My file input data does guarantee a classic multi node map, with a single root node and a dynamic number of child nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for `groupingBy` collector:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("Parent (.*) - Child (.*)");

Map<String, List<String>> map = data.stream()
        .sorted()
        .map(ptrn::matcher)
        .filter(Matcher::find)
        .collect(groupingBy(
                m -> m.group(1), 
                LinkedHashMap::new ,
                mapping(m -> m.group(2), toList())
        ));
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a merge lambda to aggregate children:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = list.stream().sorted()
        .map(line -> line.split("\\s*-\\s*"))
        .collect(toMap(a -> a[0], 
                       a -> new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(a[1])),
                      (a, b) -> {a.addAll(b); return a;}));
```

---

If your Node didn't have a `parent` field, you could get Nodes more directly:

```
List<Node> nodes = ist.stream().sorted()
    .map(line -> line.split("\\s*-\\s*"))
    .collect(groupingBy(a -> a[0]))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(e -> new Node(e.getKey()[0], e.getValue().stream()
        .map(a -> new Node(a[1], null))
        .collect(toList())))
    .collect(toList());
```

The initial grouping is a lot simpler because there is no conversation to List - the original arrays from the split are left as is.

<sub>Disclaimer: Code may not compile or work as it was thumbed in on my phone (but there's a reasonable chance it will work)</sub>

Comment: Having the `parent` field in your Node class makes it difficult and ugly to create Nodes from the map. Without it, you could easily stream the map to create a list of Node.

Comment: how do i link nodes to construct a tree without a parent field?

Comment: @Hector the children are already "linked" by being in the children list. Unless you need to navigate from and arbitrary child to its parent (a "doubly linked tree", which would be unusual - I've never seen one used), you don't need the parent field. Perhaps you are comparing the situation to a database tuple with a foreign key, but that doesn't apply in the app world.

Comment: I have added some code the goes directly from input to Nodes

Answer (score 2):

If you're aiming for a multi-map, you could use the following:

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> result = stream //stream of lines
    .sorted()
    .map(line -> line.split("\\s*-\\s*"))
    .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
            (String[] arr) -> arr[0],
            (String[] arr) -> Collections.singleton(arr[1]),
            (u, v) -> {
                Collection<String> merged = new LinkedHashSet<>(u);
                merged.addAll(v);
                return merged;
            },
            LinkedHashMap::new
        )
    );
```

The key here is the custom map collector which uses collections as values and a merge function to handle the case of duplicate keys, i.e. keys with multiple values. You can use simple `HashMap` and `HashSet` in place on `LinkedHashMap` and `LinkedHashSet` in case you don't care about the order of the elements, in that case you could remove the `sorted()` operation too.